# Allegro5 showing text doesnt work

Tags: allegro5

I have this kind of problem: I want to show the message "Hello!" near the centre of the Allegro screen before the game starts. Don't know why there is always only full window white colour after I compile the program not message "Hello!". I don't know why it doesn't show message "Hello!" . But if I erase the code between comment lines //***** program show the message "Hello!" well. Can someone can tell me how to solve this problem?

```
#include<allegro5\allegro5.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int ScreenWidth = 800, ScreenHeight = 600;

    if (!al_init())
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL, "Could not initialize Allegro 5", NULL, NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_WINDOWED);
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = al_create_display(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);//creating window with dimensions: 800:600 px
    al_set_window_position(display, 200, 100);//place from left top positioning the frame of display
    al_set_window_title(display, "Try to catch me!");

    if (!display)//show this message if sth wrong with display
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(display, "Sample Title", "Display Settings", "Display window was not created succesfully", NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    al_init_font_addon();//initialization font addon
    al_init_ttf_addon();//initialization ttf(true type font) addon

    //INTRO
    ALLEGRO_FONT *fontOrbionBlack36 = al_load_font("fonts/Orbitron Black.ttf", 36, NULL);
    al_draw_text(fontOrbionBlack36, al_map_rgb(44, 117, 255), ScreenWidth / 2, ScreenHeight / 2, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "Hello!" );
    al_rest(5.0);

    //********************************************************************************
    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_keyboard();

    ALLEGRO_COLOR electricBlue = al_map_rgb(44, 117, 255);
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = al_create_event_queue();

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());

    bool done = false;
    int x = 10, y = 10;
    int moveSpeed = 5;

    while (!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT events;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &events);
        if (events.type = ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch (events.keyboard.keycode)
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                y += moveSpeed;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                y -= moveSpeed;
                break;          
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        al_draw_rectangle(x, y, x + 20, y + 20, electricBlue, 2.0);
        al_flip_display();
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
    }
    //*****************************************************************************************

    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(10.0);//rest is very simmilar to Sleep() it is waitg function, waiting 3s then close the allegro display
    //al_destroy_font(fontOrbionBlack18);
    al_destroy_font(fontOrbionBlack36);
    al_destroy_display(display);//destroy the display at the end of the programm


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here that are preventing you from seeing the text.

1. You've set up a 'wait-for-event then draw' loop that is normally associated with the use of a timer, but you have no timer. This means that unless you trigger some sort of event (e.g. by pressing a keyboard key), `al_wait_for_event` will stall indefinitely and your program will never reach the call to `al_flip_display`. You can read more about timers [here](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial/Timers), but for the time being just know you will have to press a keyboard key to get this program to progress.
2. The ordering of your clear/draw/flip calls is a bit confusing.

Try something like this within your main loop:

```
al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));`
al_draw_rectangle(x, y, x + 20, y + 20, electricBlue, 2.0);
al_draw_text(fontOrbionBlack36, al_map_rgb(44, 117, 255), ScreenWidth / 2, ScreenHeight / 2, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "Hello!" );
al_flip_display();
```

In other words, clear first, then draw, then flip. Currently you only draw the text once (before your main loop). This means that clearing the screen will clear the text -- you need to draw the text every frame **after** clearing the screen but **before** flipping the display.

If you change those two things, you should be able to see the text after pressing a keyboard button. However, there are a few other changes that might help:

1. I'd remove those calls to `al_rest` unless they serve a useful purpose. Currently they just make you wait 5 seconds before you start your main loop (meaning you won't be able to see the text immediately even if you do press a key).
2. There's no reason to flip the display after your main loop exits, although I guess this was left over from your earlier experiments with showing text.
3. When checking the event type, use `events.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN` instead of `events.type = ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN`. Currently, you're actually assigning the value `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN` to `events.type`, overwriting whatever its original value was. Your compiler may (and probably should) have warned you about this.